# Join two queries containing grouping and subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I FULL OUTER JOIN these two tables? Both queries return same columns.

Expected `JOIN` field is `MyOrder`.

Tried already few options but always get syntax errors.

Query 1:

```
SELECT MIN(b.TimeFrame) Nazwa, MIN(b.MyOrder) MyOrder, SUM(b.Remaining) SumaFaktury
FROM (
    SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN a.DaysLate BETWEEN 1 AND 14 THEN '1 to 14'
        WHEN a.DaysLate BETWEEN 15 AND 30 THEN '15 to 30'
        ELSE 'over 30'
    END AS TimeFrame,
    CASE
        WHEN a.DaysLate BETWEEN 1 AND 14 THEN 1
        WHEN a.DaysLate BETWEEN 15 AND 30 THEN 2
        ELSE 3
    END AS MyOrder,
    Remaining, DaysLate
    FROM (
        SELECT DATEDIFF(dd, TZ, GETDATE()) DaysLate, (WN - MA) Remaining
        FROM dbo.TableA
        WHERE DATEDIFF(dd, TZ, GETDATE()) > 0
        ) a
    ) b
GROUP BY b.MyOrder
ORDER BY b.MyOrder ASC
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT MIN(b.TimeFrame) Nazwa, MIN(b.MyOrder) MyOrder, SUM(b.Remaining) SumaFaktury
FROM (
    SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN a.DaysLate BETWEEN 1 AND 14 THEN '1 to 14'
        WHEN a.DaysLate BETWEEN 15 AND 30 THEN '15 to 30'
        ELSE 'over 30'
    END AS TimeFrame,
    CASE
        WHEN a.DaysLate BETWEEN 1 AND 14 THEN 1
        WHEN a.DaysLate BETWEEN 15 AND 30 THEN 2
        ELSE 3
    END AS MyOrder,
    Remaining, DaysLate
    FROM (
        SELECT DATEDIFF(dd, TERMIN_ZAP, GETDATE()) DaysLate, (SALDO_WN) Remaining
        FROM dbo.TableB
        WHERE DATEDIFF(dd, TERMIN_ZAP, GETDATE()) > 0
        ) a
    ) b
GROUP BY b.MyOrder
ORDER BY b.MyOrder ASC
```

Comment: what is exactly the syntax error? much better to include your schema sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just perform the `FULL OUTER JOIN` using each query as a Table Expression, naming each one with different names. The `ORDER BY` needs to be extracted and included only once at the end.

For example:

```
select
  a.Nazwa as a_Nazwa, -- selected columns here
  b.Nazwa as b_Nazwa,
  coalesce(a.MyOrder, b.MyOrder) as MyOrder,
  a.SumaFaktury as a_SumaFaktury,
  b.SumaFaktury as b_SumaFaktury
from ( -- query 1
  SELECT
    MIN(b.TimeFrame) Nazwa, MIN(b.MyOrder) MyOrder,
    SUM(b.Remaining) SumaFaktury
  FROM (
      SELECT
      CASE
          WHEN a.DaysLate BETWEEN 1 AND 14 THEN '1 to 14'
          WHEN a.DaysLate BETWEEN 15 AND 30 THEN '15 to 30'
          ELSE 'over 30'
      END AS TimeFrame,
      CASE
          WHEN a.DaysLate BETWEEN 1 AND 14 THEN 1
          WHEN a.DaysLate BETWEEN 15 AND 30 THEN 2
          ELSE 3
      END AS MyOrder,
      Remaining, DaysLate
      FROM (
          SELECT DATEDIFF(dd, TZ, GETDATE()) DaysLate, (WN - MA) Remaining
          FROM dbo.TableA
          WHERE DATEDIFF(dd, TZ, GETDATE()) > 0
          ) a
      ) b
  GROUP BY b.MyOrder
) a
full outer join ( -- query 2
  SELECT
    MIN(b.TimeFrame) Nazwa, MIN(b.MyOrder) MyOrder, 
    SUM(b.Remaining) SumaFaktury
  FROM (
      SELECT
      CASE
          WHEN a.DaysLate BETWEEN 1 AND 14 THEN '1 to 14'
          WHEN a.DaysLate BETWEEN 15 AND 30 THEN '15 to 30'
          ELSE 'over 30'
      END AS TimeFrame,
      CASE
          WHEN a.DaysLate BETWEEN 1 AND 14 THEN 1
          WHEN a.DaysLate BETWEEN 15 AND 30 THEN 2
          ELSE 3
      END AS MyOrder,
      Remaining, DaysLate
      FROM (
          SELECT DATEDIFF(dd, TERMIN_ZAP, GETDATE()) DaysLate, (SALDO_WN) Remaining
          FROM dbo.TableB
          WHERE DATEDIFF(dd, TERMIN_ZAP, GETDATE()) > 0
          ) a
      ) b
  GROUP BY b.MyOrder
) b on a.MyOrder = b.MyOrder -- the join condition
order by coalesce(a.MyOrder, b.MyOrder) ASC -- the ordering
```

In the main selection you may want to use `COALESCE()` or not, depending on how do you want to process the columns.

Comment: @Nickolay Yes, you spotted that right. I think the queries themselves are not 100% tuned up.

Comment: The main problem was that I was trying to join both queries without the additional top SELECT. Corrected SELECT MIN(b.MyOrder) issue as well.